# Why should we create A DNS record for subdomains when we can do it via httpd.conf?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to implement a blog in my site with usernames as subdomains like `user1.domain.com`.
I've read bunch of articles that was mentioned to create an A record like below in DNS:

```
*.domain.com A 127.0.0.1 ;OR you site ip address
```

Then use .htaccess to redirect requests from subdomains to a folder in your server.

But I find another approach that was said to just modify your httpd.conf as below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /abs/path/to/webroot
        ServerName   domainname.com
        ServerAlias *.domainname.com
        <Directory /abs/path/to/webroot>
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then retrieve subdomains via `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.
The question is why should someone use htaccess and put pressure on apache and create A DNS record when we can do a simple thing like `ServerAlias *.domainname.com` in `httpd.conf`?
I appreciate in advance for your views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup both a wildcard DNS record and configure a server alias in `httpd.conf` to enable the hosting of arbitrary sub domains.  They configure completely different things.

Add the wildcard DNS records is what allows clients to determine the IP address of your sub domain.  With the wildcard DNS record about `user1.domain.com` will resolve to `127.0.0.1`.  If you do not have a DNS record no `user1.domain.com` will not be a valid name and it will not resolve to an IP address.  the DNS record is to allow clients to connect to your server.

The `httpd.conf` configuration is local to your Apache server.  It does not affect clients.  The line `ServerAlias *.domainname.com` will configure Apache to tell it to process the arbitrary sub domains.  Client's will not be directly affected by this setting.

Answer (score 2):

You have added the `ServerAlias`, but for your computer to find that `user1.domain.com` and `user2.domain.com` should resolve to `127.0.0.1`, you need to update your `HOSTS` file or `DNS Table`.

The configuration you have written is for Apache Server for handling the redirects when the user requests the domain. So, essentially, either you need a `Dynamic HOSTS` file or a service which resolves `*.domain.com` to your `127.0.0.1` server.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: So it's not possible to implement subdomains without `A record`, right?

Comment: Unfortunately no... :( But you can do using Dynamic DNS tools. Because, the `HOSTS` file doesn't support wildcard characters like `*`!